# Hide All Page + Project titles in Virb.com

Tags: css

I'm having some trouble finding the best way to hide the project titles on my virb website. The main gallery view here: http://katekoeppel.com shows the project title below each image. Is there a good way to remove all of these titles completely?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to hide the `<h2>`. So, give this CSS:

```css
#main-content .index .normal li a .titles h2,
#main-content .index .large li a .titles h2 {display: none;}
```

Let us know in the comments, if you face difficulty in adding the CSS. Also, please refrain from posting link only questions. You need to add the CSS in `base.css`.

**Preview:**

[image]